# Can a member of a class be named the same name as its type (another class)?

Tags: c++, g++, implementation, clang, visual-c++-2012

Trying to compile the following code on different compilers gives me two different results:

```
struct S{};
struct T{S S;};
int main(){}
```

As you can see, inside `T`, I have an object named the same as the previously defined class `S`.

---

On GCC 4.7.2, [I get the following error](http://liveworkspace.org/code/6cd3eb7604aac15c7fc5c9005e3c561b) pertaining to the `S S;` declaration inside `T`:

> error: declaration of 'S T::S' [-fpermissive]
>    error: changes meaning of 'S' from 'struct S' [-fpermissive]

However, moving it outside of the class (or into `main`) [works fine](http://liveworkspace.org/code/7782c16e75dceb383e6af7361c0551cc):

```
struct S{};
S S;
int main(){}
```

What exactly does it mean by the error it's giving me?

---

In Visual Studio 2012, the whole thing compiles and runs without any errors. Pasting it into [this Clang 3.0 compiler](http://llvm.org/demo/) gives me no errors as well.

Which is right? Can I actually do this or not?

Comment: Ah, I see – I misread the diagnostic.

Comment: @ildjarn, It is a rather weird flag. It seems to work in reverse. Normally, the flag responsible for a warning appears in the square brackets.

Comment: Just don't. What's the point? Confuse? Note that after you have done that, you can no longer refer to the type `S` in member functions without explicitly qualifying the namespace...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, I realize that. I wasn't planning on doing it :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

gcc is correct, from [3.3.7 Class Scope]

> A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its
>   context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No
>   diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

However, note that `no diagnostic is required`, so all compilers are conforming.

The reason is because of how class scope works. When you write `S S;` `S` is visible within the **entire** class and changes the meaning when you use `S`.

```
struct S{};
struct T{
    void foo()
    { 
        S myS; // Not possible anymore because S refers to local S
    }
    S S;
};
```

Comment: The rationale, IIRC, is to allow the definition of class member functions inside the class. Name lookup inside them would be funky if the meaning of a name changes within a class. (It's already hard enough as-is).

Comment: The same example works perfectly with the correct semantics in C#. `S`member is also usable with correct semantics. C# is able to distinguish the context where `S` is used and is not clear why C++ compilers shouldn't be able to do the same.

Answer (score 8):

@JesseGood provide a complete answer, but if you really want to do this without any error, you can use type's full name and it will work as follow:

```
struct S {};
struct T { ::S S; };
int main() {return 0;}
```

No there is no error, since `S` in your class is `T::S` and its type is `::S`!

Answer (score 6):

This code is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. Like the diagnostic says, if a declaration uses a name and the name has a different meaning than it would have when looked up at the end of the class definition, the programm is illformed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: Another day where I'm bettering myself! +1