# Member with the same name of the type

Tags: c++

I want to create a member function with the same name of the returning type. Example:

```
class A { };

class B {
public:
    A& A() { return *a; }
private:
    A* a;
};
```

However, the compiler won't let me. I tried to change the type of the member return type to `::A` (as sugested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12944488/105398), but with no avail. I know I could just change the member name, but I just want to understand why does it has this restriction, and what are my workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare a member called `A` you can no longer use the type `A` without an explicit namespace. You need to change every occurrence of the type A to `::A`.

The corrected code looks like:

```
class A { };

class B {
    public:
        ::A& A() { return *a; }
    private:
        ::A* a;
};
```

### Fixed code on codepad:

http://codepad.org/cilF9rKm

Answer (score 0):

That's because a member with the same name as the class is a constructor. However, you try to declare one with a type, which is an error. You can only define constructors the way the language wants you too (without an explicit return type).

For example, if you had a method in `B` that said

```
A x = A();
```

it is ambiguous whether you are calling `B::A()` or are constructing a new A object.

Comment: The member has a different name and is not a constructor. The class is called `A` and the member is called `B`.