# Why do Clang and MSVC not like a member typedef declaration with a redundant set of parentheses?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, typedef

Consider

```
using foo = int;

struct A {
    typedef A (foo)();
};
```

GCC and ICC accept the snippet, while Clang and MSVC reject it. Clang's error message is

> ```
> <source>:4:15: error: function cannot return function type 'void ()'
>     typedef A (foo)();
>               ^
> <source>:4:13: error: typedef name must be an identifier
>     typedef A (foo)();
>             ^
> 2 errors generated.
> ```

And MSVC says

> ```
> <source>(4,15): error C2091: function returns function
>     typedef A (foo)();
>               ^
> ```

([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dc9Ksx))

Why do Clang and MSVC produce this error? Which compilers are correct?

(I'm specifically looking for quotation from the standard or any defect report.)

Comment: Rule of thumb: If Clang and GCC disagree, Clang is correct. If MSVC and GCC disagree, GCC is correct. Since Clang and MSVC agree with each other and disagree with GCC, this is a non-transitive error!

Comment: EDG rules them all, but not everyone has access to EDG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Clang is wrong: `foo` in the typedef declaration in `A` does not refer to the namespace-scope *typedef-name* `foo`

W.r.t. the standard rules, the enclosing namespace/scope alias declaration

> ```
> using foo = int;
> ```

is a red herring; within the declarative scope of class `A` it will be shadowed by names *declared* in `A`

```
#include <type_traits>

using foo = int;
struct A {
    using foo = char;
    foo x;
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<foo, int>,"");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<A::foo, char>,"");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(A::x), char>,"");
```

The key here being that `typedef A (foo)();` *declares* the name `foo` within the declarative region of `A`, as per [[dcl.spec]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec#3) [**emphasis** mine]:

> If a *type-name* is encountered while parsing a *decl-specifier-seq*, it is interpreted as part of the *decl-specifier-seq* **if and only if there is no previous** *defining-type-specifier* other than a *cv-qualifier* in the *decl-specifier-seq*.

Specifically, this means that in the *typedef declaration*

> ```
> typedef A (foo)();
> ```

even if there is an existing [*typedef-name*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.typedef#1) `foo`, that `foo` is not considered in the typedef declaration, namely it is not considered as a *type-name* part of the *decl-specifier-seq* of `typedef A (foo)()`, as `A` has already been encountered previous to it, and `A` is a valid *defining-type-specifier*. Thus, the original example:

> ```
> using foo = int;
>
> struct A {
>     typedef A (foo)();
> };
> ```

can be reduced to:

```
// (i)
struct A {
    typedef A (foo)();  // #1
};
```

which declares the typedef name `foo` in `A` (`A::foo`), where the paranthese around the name are redundant, and the typedef declaration at #1 can likewise be written as

```
// (ii)
struct A {
    typedef A foo();  // #1
};
```

and can likewise be introduced using an *alias declaration* ([[dcl.typedef]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.typedef#2)):

```
// (iii)
struct A {
    using foo = A();
};
```

`(i)`, `(ii)` and `(iii)` are accepted by both GCC and Clang.

Finally, we may note that Clang accepts the following program:

```
using foo = int;
struct A {
    typedef A foo();
    using bar = A();
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<A::foo, A::bar>,"");
```

and that the root issue of the example of the OP is arguably a Clang bug, where Clang fails to adhere to [dcl.spec]/3 and interprets the outer-scope *typedef-name* `foo` as part of the *decl-specifier-seq* of the inner-scope typedef declaration, only for the case where the latter has wrapped the shadowed name `foo` in parantheses.

Comment: I agree with your analysis, though strictly speaking [dcl.spec]/3 also makes `A(size_t);` a (ill-formed) data member declaration, while all compilers treat it as a constructor declaration when `size_t` is in scope and denotes a type. But since I can't find a saner disambiguation rule, I guess that's all we have.

Comment: @cpplearner Just `A(size_t)` arguably falls under the special case of [\[class.mem\]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mem#10), in so particularly identifying a constructor/destructor/conversion function for which [dcl.spec]/3 does not apply (as the _decl-specifier-seq_ has been omitted). It could arguably be a conflict between [class.mem]/10 and [dcl.spec]/3 when (intending to) omitting the _decl-specifier-seq_ for e.g. declaring a constructor, but any sane interpretation would let [class.mem]/10 take precedence there. When `typename` _is_ present, there is no conflict.

Comment: @cpplearner Do you agree with my previous (comment) statement that [class.mem]/10 would govern your example of `A(size_t)`; such that there is actually a disambiguation rule in place here?

Comment: I'm not sure. Even if it does, I think it fails to account for `explicit A(size_t)` or `constexpr A(size_t)`. (Since `explicit` and `constexpr` are *decl-specifier*s, the *decl-specifier-seq* is not omitted, and then [dcl.spec]/3 applies.)

Comment: @cpplearner The `explicit` case is ruled (and disambiguated) by [\[dcl.fct.spec\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.spec#3). The `constexpr` case is weaker, though, I agree, but [\[dcl.constexpr\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.constexpr#1) does explicitly list the cases for where it _may_ be used, and a typedef declaration is not part of it, meaning both of them cannot co-exist, and in such we have (weaker/implicit) disambiguation.

Answer (score 4):

Both Clang and MSVC are ignoring the `typedef` specifier and reading the declaration as that of a constructor (that is, `A` is the constructor name) accepting parameter types `(foo)` (that is, `(int)`) and "returning" a function type signified by the trailing parentheses `()`.

Yes, constructors don't have return types; but if they *did* have return types they would have return type `A`, so the additional `()` at the end makes these compilers think that you now have a constructor with return type the function type `A()`.

This is supported by noting that the following "similar" declarations have similar error messages:

```
A (foo)();
typedef ~A(foo)();
```

Also, by adding `static` we can get an illuminating error message from MSVC:

```
A static (int)();
error C2574: '(__cdecl *A::A(int))(void)': cannot be declared static
```

For workarounds: under Clang (but not MSVC) you can move the `typedef` specifier to the right, or use an elaborated type specifier:

```
A typedef (foo)();
typedef struct A (foo)();
```

Under all compilers you can remove or add parentheses:

```
typedef A foo();
typedef A ((foo))();
```

And you can always update to a type alias:

```
using foo = A();
```

Comment: I think compilers are treating `A` as the constructor name. (`A (foo)` is a valid constructor declaration, and apparently all compilers believe that it's still a constructor declaration if it's followed by `()`.) I also believe that `A static (foo)();` is a valid declaration (as it can't be mistaken for a constructor declaration).

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to put it. You're right on `A static (foo)();` - it's the declaration of a static member function named `foo`. I think I can still get something useful out of a C2574 error though.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the meaning of `foo` from `int` to `A()` when you redeclare it inside `A`. This violates [basic.scope.class#2](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.class#2):

> A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

Since this is IFNDR, all compilers are conforming.

Comment: Interesting reading, but I'd argue that (1) the name `foo` is "declared", not "used" in the class (2) this does not explain the error message given.

Comment: @cpplearner I think compilers are allowed to reject code that does this, even if `N` is not used. I seem to remember other cases where compilers reject code based on this rule. I'll take a look.

Comment: @cpplearner Here's a related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681873), also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41515989), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943607).

Comment: [Clang accepts](https://godbolt.org/z/s1xfdj) both `typedef A foo()` and `typedef A (*foo)()`, so this doesn't seem to be the problem.  Also the declaration in the original question doesn't use the previous typedef of `foo`.  Another interesting thing is if you use a different type from the inclosing struct, it also works (`struct C` in the demo link).

Comment: @cpplearner I might be wrong about the rule applying here, but if it does apply, listing violations that don't get rejected doesn't say much. Clang accepts `typedef A ((foo))();` for example. Is your question asking what those specific diagnostics mean?

Comment: @cigien If I understand correctly the equivalent code `using foo = A();` doesn't violate this rule.  In `typedef A (foo)();` `foo` should only be an identifier, so it's previous alias to `int` shouldn't matter as it isn't used.  This seems like a parsing ambiguity problem to me, especially based on the error message being _function cannot return function type_.

Comment: @IlCapitano Oh, my answer is claiming that `using foo = A();` is ifndr as well. The answer could be wrong.

Comment: @cigien Based on the examples provided at [basic.scope.class#5](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.class#5) the declaration itself doesn't violate this rule, but using `foo` in class scope before the `using` alias does.  Similar to `i` and `X::i` in the example.

Comment: @IlCapitano _Based on the examples provided at basic.scope.class#5 the declaration itself doesn't violate this rule_ Based on the example, the declaration itself **does** violate the rule. The fact that `foo` is not "used" before redeclaration changes nothing.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer How so?  There's no mention of `typedef long T;` inside `struct Y` being in violation of the rule, which is the same case here.  Only `T a;` on the previous line is a problem.

Comment: @IlCapitano see the last example

Comment: @LanguageLawyer But that's not what is happening here.

Comment: I don't believe this applies here. In the examples you link to, e.g. `using Foo = Foo;`, the same _name_ is used as 1) a _name_ for the class-scope typedef/alias declaration, and 2) an existing _type-name_ due to a before-class declaration, and 3) a valid _defining-type-specifier_ for the class-scope typedef/alias declaration. As I've shown in my example, `foo` in the typedef declaration `typedef A (foo)();` is not considered as a _type-name_ part of the _decl-specifier-seq_ of the typedef declaration, and thus there is no changing of the meaning of `foo` (particularly, 3) does not apply).

Comment: The passage means that you cannot declare a name outside of a class, then use it inside of a class, then declare it inside the same class to mean something else. It doesn't mean that you cannot shadow names.